# Prevent React Native Modal from returning focus to TextInput when closed

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, focus, onfocus

I have a situation where I am using the `onFocus` method of a `TextInput` (call it "main TextInput") to open a Modal. The problem I'm having is when I focus on a separate `TextInput` inside the Modal (call it "Modal TextInput") and then close the Modal, the `onFocus` method of the main `TextInput` fires again and reopens the Modal. If at that point I close the Modal without focusing on the Modal `TextInput`, the main `TextInput` doesn't lose and regain focus, so the Modal does not reopen.

It's as if the main `TextInput` loses focus to the Modal `TextInput` and then closing the Modal returns the focus to the main `TextInput` with the following catch. As far as I can tell, the main `TextInput` does not actually lose focus because I created a simple console log test of the `onBlur` method and it's not firing.

I've seen a solution where someone used the blur method prior to actually opening the Modal, but they were using a button to open the Modal so they had an `onPress` they could use to execute multiple commands whereas I'm using the `onFocus` so the Modal immediately opens.

I attempted using the `useRef` hook to focus on an "invisible" `TextInput` when the `onDismiss` method of the Modal is called, but the behavior is the same. The weird thing there is using console logs (yes I'm an amateur) to see the order of events shows the `onFocus` of the main `TextInput` occurring again before the Modal `onDismiss`.

If someone knows a way to prevent this behavior, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option.

Set a new piece of state to track whether the modal should open.  If you're using hooks:

```js
// screen body
const [modalShouldOpen, setModalShouldOpen] = useState(true);
```

You probably already have a piece of state that tracks whether the modal is open:

```js
const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
```

When you invoke `setIsModalOpen(true)` in the `onFocus` callback of your main text input, also invoke `setModalShouldOpen(false)`.  The callback must also be altered to only open the modal if it should open.

```js
const onFocus = () => {
  if (!modalShouldOpen) return;

  setIsModalOpen(true);
  setModalShouldOpen(false);
}
```

Then you can set modalShouldOpen back to true in the onBlur method of the main TextInput.  Full pseudocode below.

```js
export default function MainScreen() {
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [modalShouldOpen, setModalShouldOpen] = useState(true);

  const onMainTextInputFocus = () => {
    if (!modalShouldOpen) return;

    setIsModalOpen(true);
    setModalShouldOpen(false);
  }

  const onMainTextInputBlur = () => {
    setModalShouldOpen(true);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput onFocus={onMainTextInputFocus} onBlur={onMainInputBlur} />
    
      <Modal show={isModalOpen}>
        ...
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Abe, thanks so much for your input and code example. You were right about me already using state and the solution of using a separate function to control that state (with the extra "should" state) is exactly what I needed. Despite this making sense logically, I did have a problem with the modal still returning focus to the TextInput. Maybe I was doing something wrong or maybe it's unavoidable. So the final solution ended up being to implement this as well as useRef with my "invisible" TextInput to just entirely shift the focus to a different component before opening the modal.

Comment: No problem!  That's annoying that you had to do the workaround.  Another workaround could be to use `setTimeout` on the `setModalShouldOpen` call when the modal is closed: `setTimeout(() => setModalShouldOpen(true), 500)`.  As long as `onFocus` is called before 500ms in this example, `modalShouldOpen` should still be set to false when it runs.  Clunky, but at least wouldn't be an extra element.